# Module error running script in command line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have script, call it `tst.py` where when I run it in the Python console or Terminal of PyCharm there are no issues, however when I call the script in the command prompt I get a long error. I get this error even when I copy the exact command from running in the Terminal of PyCharm

A simplified version of the script looks like

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'tst1': [1, 2],
       'tst2': [3, 4],
       'tst3': [5, 6]}

myDf = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(myDf)
```

When I run in the command line using:

```
C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\envs\pers36\python.exe H:/Experiments/test.py
```

The error I get is:

```
C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\envs\pers36\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:138: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Experiments/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\envs\pers36\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.6 from "C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\envs\pers36\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have checked the Python version in my IDE using `sys.version` and can see it is 3.6.13. I have also checked the website suggested and can't see anything obvious (the issue is in the command prompt not Anaconda/Conda/PyCharm). It looks like an environment issue, but I would have thought I was running with the exact same environment and interpreter given I point to it in the command prompt.

Comment: Does the error continue to resist if you remove the `C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\envs\pers36\python.exe` directory from the execution line?

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons installed and PyCharm use one Python but command line use other Python. In PyCharm you can print `sys.executable` to ge path to Python used by PyCharm. And later use this path to run script in command line.

Comment: @furas yes there are more than one versions of Python. When I run sys.executable I get C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\envs\pers36\python.exe which is what I was using in the command line, but it's as if this version is not being picked up. In cmd line I run: C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\envs\pers36\python.exe H:/Experiments/test.py

Comment: @PythonicUser no it doesn't, however there is a different (expected) error because other modules are missing, hence why I was trying to run with the pers36 environment as it as specific modules installed. Although this does show that for some reason it's not properly picking up the Python version when I run the way I do

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

From the start menu: START > RUN c:\path_to_scripts\my_script.cmd, OK

If the filename includes any spaces, then you will need to surround the command with quotes:

"c:\path to scripts\my script.cmd"

Open a new CMD prompt by choosing START > RUN cmd, OK

From the command line, enter the name of the script and press return.

**Option 2:**

try importing pandas first using this command ======>pip install pandas